# QtQuick application starts in a client machine but not in another

Tags: qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

I have a **QtQuick** application based on **Qt5.1** that starts on my machine (developer-WIN7) and on another (client-WIN8) machine but not on another client(WIN7) (there is no errors) ?

the previous version of my app which uses **Qt5.0.2** works good on the same client.

Have you an idea of what the problem is how can i find the problem ?

Thank you.

**Edit:**
I have deleted the grafic driver and the application is opened but there is a blank screen.

Comment: Which OS? Which platform? Are you correctly following the deployment manual? Less information you give, less are the chances of getting a good reply...

Comment: The client machine on that the application works has a Windows 8 OS and the second machine on that it don't work has Windows 7 as OS.

Comment: @peppe i follow the same instructions as for Qt5.0.2 version.

Comment: I have made some tests and after deleting the grafic card driver it works but there is a blank screen.

Comment: Are you using the OpenGL build of Qt, and the target machine is missing OpenGL drivers?

Comment: @peppe. I think that i'm using the OpenGL build of Qt.
Here is the installation file name : **"qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-rc1-mingw48_opengl-x86-offline.exe"** what should i do ?
The grafic card of the other machine is : **Mobil Intel(R) 945 Express Chipset Family**.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the strong, bad feeling that you don't have OpenGL 2/3 support with such a card, only Direct3D 9/10. Therefore, please try using the ANGLE build of Qt (i.e. the one *not* marked with OpenGL).

Comment: @peppe. i searched for a non OpenGL build but i don't find one for the Qt5.1 version.

Comment: The RC2 should be out any moment soon, maybe a ANGLE+MinGW build will be there. Otherwise, please try compiling from sources.

Comment: @peppe. Thank you for all this responses. Now i know what the problem is.
I need that working version for tomorrow. Could you advice me on how to do this compilation ?

Comment: I have some new things related to this question. Should i create a new question ?

Comment: @peppe. I have used the non-opengl (angle) msvc 2012 version and it works now. Thank you.